# Jquery Autocomplete: How to create the autocomplete menu with my own html or how to store and retrieve the `id` like data from the menu?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I tried to use jquery autocomplete in my application. i am returning objects like this,

```
obj{id:"12121", name:"XXXXXX"}
```

I want to show the `name` in the menu and also need to get the `id`.

How to wrap it with the menu html and retrieve it

Now the auto generated menu mark up is looks like this,

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">XXXXXX</a></li>
```

I want to have the id of my object in `<a>` element's id attribute and name as usual.

Like this,

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a id='12121' class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">XXXXXX</a></li>
```

Can we do this with jquery auto-complete?!

Any suggestions would be appreciative.

Thanks~!

Comment: check the example here, it's the exact same thing you want to do http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: @Yads: Thanks man. Its exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently use a JSON data object (from sourcefile.php) that looks like this:

```
{"label":"Reljac, Jason","value":"Reljac, Jason","id":"620"}
```

I then use this:

```
$("#field").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: "http://sourcefile.php",

    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#po_vendor').val(ui.item.id);
        $("#po_vendorDisplay").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    }
})
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .append( "<a>"+ item.label + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

That displays **Reljac, Jason** in the drop down while **620** is picked up by autocomplete

Comment: If you don't literally need the item id as part of the <a> then this is definitely the better approach.

Comment: Looking at the initial question and my answer more I am using an extra hidden element (po_vendor) to store the id so this may not get you what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

We modified our autocompleter to use checkboxes as part of the dropdown, but to fix your situation I think you'd want something like this:

```
$( '#autocompleter' ).autocomplete({
    source: "yourautocompleter.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
            //your select event here
    }

}).data( 'autocomplete' )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( '<li class="ui-menu-item"></li>' )
        .data( 'item.autocomplete', item )
        .append( '<a class="ui-corner-all" id="' + item.id + '">' + item.label + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

**Edit: Removed a lot of irrelevant code.**

Comment: This does get the id into the <a> tag unlike my example that stuck it in an extra, hidden field